# jQuery not adding class to element properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working on a new feature for my little project which takes a command from the input (write into input: make a box called somename) and if it detects that the command is "make a box called somename", it will create a div with the class of somename. But, when I try to add styling to the `div` element, nothing happens. The problem lies in the line above the switch statement's `break;`

```js
// checks if word is in string s
function wordInString(s, word){
  return new RegExp( '\\b' + word + '\\b', 'i').test(s);
}

$('input').keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    let input = $(this).val();
    console.log("Initial Input: " + input);


    const Commands = ['call it', 'name it', 'make a box called'];

    split_input = input.split(" ");

    var arrayLength = Commands.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        command = Commands[i];
        console.log(command);
        let wordFound = wordInString(input, command);
        if (wordFound) {
          console.log("Command found: " + command)
          switch (command) {
            case "make a box called":
              let name = split_input[4];
              console.log("Box name: " + name)
              $('.Dragon').append($('<div>', {class: name}));

              // this is the problem line, I do not quite get why it won't w ork
              $('.'.concat(name)).addClass({'background-color': 'green', 'height': '50px', 'width': '50px'});

              break;
            default:

          }
        }
    }

    $(this).val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Dependencies -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <title>CodeDragon</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/master.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="Dragon"></div>


    <input type="text" name="_input" value="">
    <script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use jquery's [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method instead of addClass there, use the same syntax, as in :

```
$('.'.concat(name)).css({'background-color': 'green', 'height': '50px', 'width': '50px'});
```

Comment: O my, my brain thought I had written css instead of addClass, must have unconcoussly written it. Another pair of eyes do miracles, thank you so much Mohammaed!!

Comment: @Holiday the SO way to thank people is also to _accept_ the answer that helped you solve your issue the best way. It also means to others that your issue is fixed. Once you get enough _reputation_, [you will be able](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) to _upvote_.

Comment: @ghybs Until I am able to upvote, I will thank the people who helped me, which is a common decency.

Comment: @Holiday make sure you read carefully: I _never_ said not to thank. But to _also_ "accept" one of the answers. You should have the accept button on top left of answers. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you trying to use wrong method. Try `css` instead of `addClass`

```
.addClass({'background-color': 'green', 'height': '50px', 'width': '50px'});
```

It has to be

```
.css({'background-color': 'green', 'height': '50px', 'width': '50px'});
```

Answer (score 1):

For additional clarity, the reason you can't use the .addClas() method is because "background-color" is not a class, it's a css property.  Thus, you have to use the .css() method to set it.

```
.css({'background-color': 'green', 'height': '50px', 'width': '50px'});
```